# Ubuntu 15.04 (fully updated as of 16/06/15) and Wifi Realtek RTL8723BE

Tags: wireless, drivers, 15.04, realtek-wireless

Afternoon All,

I have a laptop (HP Probook 455 G2) running 15.04. A clean install...... it was working with 12.04 upwards.....

A seemless install, but with one MAJOR problem. Wifi is enabled, but i cannot see any wifi networks or connect to any hidden ones. Not too sure where to go from here....please see below results from what little linux commands i know!! :)

output for `lspci -v`:

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2235
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
Memory at d5804000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at d5800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2231
Physical Slot: 0
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
Memory at d4800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be

03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2235
Physical Slot: 0-1
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 34
Memory at d3800000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
```

output for `lspci -nn`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Root Complex [1022:1422]
00:00.2 IOMMU [0806]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) I/O Memory Management Unit [1022:1423]
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kaveri [Radeon R6 Graphics] [1002:130a]
00:01.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kaveri HDMI/DP Audio Controller [1002:1308]
00:02.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:1424]
00:03.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:1424]
00:03.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Root Port [1022:1426]
00:03.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Root Port [1022:1426]
00:03.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Root Port [1022:1426]
00:04.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:1424]
00:10.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller [1022:7814] (rev 09)
00:11.0 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1022:7801] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller [1022:7807] (rev 11)
00:12.2 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller [1022:7808] (rev 11)
00:13.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller [1022:7807] (rev 11)
00:13.2 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller [1022:7808] (rev 11)
00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller [1022:780b] (rev 16)
00:14.2 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller [1022:780d] (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge [1022:780e] (rev 11)
00:14.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH PCI Bridge [1022:780f] (rev 40)
00:14.5 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller [1022:7809] (rev 11)
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 0 [1022:141a]
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 1 [1022:141b]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 2 [1022:141c]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 3 [1022:141d]
00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 4 [1022:141e]
00:18.5 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 5 [1022:141f]
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5229] (rev 01)
```

output for `lsmod | grep 819`

```
amdkfd                 81920  1 
r8169                  81920  0
```

output for `modinfo r8192e_pci | grep 8192`:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8192e/rtl8192e/r8192e_pci.ko
firmware:       RTL8192E/data.img
firmware:       RTL8192E/main.img
firmware:       RTL8192E/boot.img
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008192sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
```

output for `iwconfig`:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

output for `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan`:

```
wlan0     No scan results
```

output for `rfkill list all`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
```

RECOMENDED FIX: echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf

output for `modinfo -p rtl8723be`:

```
swlps: (bool)
swenc:using hardware crypto (default 0 [hardware])
 (bool)
ips:using no link power save (default 1 is open)
 (bool)
fwlps:using linked fw control power save (default 1 is open)
 (bool)
msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 0)

debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)
 (bool)
```

Any help will be gratefully appreciated an if we get it working shall do a cartwheel!! :)

Answer (score 0):

i cannot directly answer to you with detailed steps (writing from a windows install) but there you go:

```
  git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
```

and the simply compile with

```
  make
```

if all is well then do

```
sudo make install
```

PS: you need a relatively new kernel (after 3.18 i believe) and headers to match it.
Also, seems support is still wip: [same laptop](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/49)

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu 15.04 requires `options rtl8723be msi=1 ips=0` in the `/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` file on some boxes (HP455G2)

[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsRealTek)

Comment: Please review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)**